# Mbed ATCmdParser::recv using scanf type parameters yielding incorrect string results

Tags: c++, scanf, at-command, mbed

Using the mbed microcontroller platform to query a GSM module using AT Commands.
The following code does not work, it results in a failed request from timeout :

```
UARTSerial bus(PB_10, PB_11, 115200);
bus.set_flow_control(Serial::RTSCTS, PB_14, PB_13);
ATCmdParser parser(&bus, AT_DELIMINATOR);

char buffer[10];
parser.send("AT+CPIN?");
if (parser.recv("+CPIN: %2s", buffer))
{
    log->info("[AT+CPIN?] Returned result %s", buffer);
} else {
    log->info("[AT+CPIN?] Request failed");
}
```

### The problem

The problem is the %2s parameter in the call to `parser.recv("+CPIN: %2s", buffer)` :

1. If I remove the %2s the call succeeds but obviously I am not reading in any parameters.

   `parser.recv("+CPIN: ")`
2. Or, I can change the %2s to %s but only the first character is read.

   `parser.recv("+CPIN: %s", buffer)` yields buffer = `S` really the GSM modules is sending `SIM PIN`
3. I have also tried using %c instead of %s for scenario 2 but am getting the same results.
4. Scenarios 2 and 3 fail also when using scanf() instead of recv()

   `parser.scanf("+CPIN: %s\r", buffer)`

### Question

How can I read the whole string before the line deliminator ?
Bonus points if you can tell me how to read a string with a space in it !

### Expected results

One of the following values should be copied into `buffer` :

- READY
- SIM PIN
- SIM PUK
- PH-SIM PIN
- PH-FSIM PIN
- PH-FSIM PUK
- SIM PIN2
- SIM PUK2
- PH-NET PIN
- PH-NET PUK
- PH-NETSUB PIN
- PH-NETSUB PUK
- PH-SP PIN
- PH-SP PUK
- PH-CORP PIN
- PH-CORP PUK
- PH-MCL PIN

Comment: Actually option 4 seem fine to me. What do you log in that case?

Comment: @Cubo78 only the first character...

Comment: I'm sorry. It makes not sense for me. The only way I can help is noticing that buffer would not be able to contain all the strings you listed. For example "PH-NETSUB PUK" would require 13+1 characters.